# Float doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a page here: 
http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/founders/

The part where it says "MICHAEL GARDNER / CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER" won't float just like the first text and image.

Do you have any idea why its not floating?

Here's the whole codes:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; float: left;">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/tony-beatty.jpg" alt="tony-beatty" width="351" height="360" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-15670" style="margin-right: 15px; border: 1px solid #dedede; padding: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);
box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);"/>
</div>

<div style="float: right; margin-top: 11px;">
<h3>TONY BEATTY / CHIEF OPERATIONS OFFICER</h3>

Music Inc. Magazine calls Tony the <em>"Million Dollar Closer”</em>

After 25 years mastering the art of selling Music Inc. Magazine calls Tony the "million dollar closer.” Tony is not
only an extremely accomplished sales genius, but he considers himself a master story teller. Originally educated in
Music and Acting, Tony’s passion for story selling was express on the theatrical stage. After more than 50
productions his love of music and performance led him to small piano store in St. George Utah where he
combined story telling with enrolling people into music making.

In 2011, playing with video and Social Media, Tony was key in launching The Piano Guys YouTube Channel. To be
excellent in his new craft of video production, Tony received a B.S. Degree in Digital Film Production from Dixie
State University in 2013 which adds to his repertoire of talents. Talents he uses to enroll people into their own
story, vision, and purpose.

Because of Tony’s passion for learning the art of enrollment and personal development he has studied and trained
with some of the most well-known personal educators and facilitators from around the country, such as; Tom
Hopkins, Zig Ziglar, Brian Tracy and John Maxwell. Tony recognizes the behind every person is a story, likewise
products and services that enhance our lives are created through stories. Magic happens when stories merge and
fulfillment in life is achieved.

After training with Michael Gardner, Tony’s story telling took on a whole new meaning. “Life is a story, the human
story. Most peoples make up victim stories that get in the way who they truly are. Once we start recognizing the
truth of our story, we can then finish our story.”

Tony is energetic, enthusiastic and driven by people's success in life. He has comprehensive experience in human
relations inside and outside the retail and services arena. He is characterized as considerate, dependable,
honest, straightforward, hard-working, and personable, with strong management skills, including sales, marketing
and customer relationship management experience develop throughout the last 25 years.
Tony offers a combination of creative talents and a strong personal experience with people from all walks of life.
He devotes time to people while drawing on their energy, experiences and vision to make a positive contribution in
peoples lives.

</div>

<div style="clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px;"> </div>


<div style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid red;">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/mike-gardner.jpg" alt="mike-gardner" width="351" height="360" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-15669" style="margin-right: 15px; border: 1px solid #dedede; padding: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1); box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);"/>
</div>

<div style="float: right; margin-top: 11px; border: 1px solid red;">
<h3>MICHAEL GARDNER / CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER</h3>

Michael Gardner is known as the Master Trainer.

Michael is able to train students at a new depth of knowledge that they have not experienced before, their lives
truly changed. They are able to create a passion for life and newfound wealth. Gifted would be an understatement
in referring to Michael Gardner.

Michael has spent the past 25 years challenging and inspiring over 10,000 people to discover that they are more
powerful than they believe. As a result, he is the premier trainer and coach and his field. Michael's direct
approach, results driven training and coaching has been experienced by CEOs, entrepreneurs, small business
owners, network marketing founders and distributors, athletes, entertainers, students and parents, and anyone
who has a desire to discover they are more powerful than they believe.

Michael has one purpose and one purpose only. That is to support his students to get what they want and more.
His students and clients discover that Michael is very direct, honest and focused. His passion is to change and
support them in their pursuits of self discovery.

Michael has a unique ability to point out the lies and stories people tell themselves to justify where they have fallen short. Even those who have achieved amazing levels of success in life are surprised by how much greater the
results they create are as a result of participating in Michael's training. Past students and clients share a greater sense of power in their lives, as well as becoming more effective in their careers, and a greater sense of peace and fulfillment in their lives.

The main focus of Michael's training and coaching are: accountability, commitment, current pension, honesty,
integrity and trust.

Whether you feel you are successful in your personal life or not, whether you feel you are already fulfilled and life is good, you will benefit exponentially to Michael's training and coaching.

If you are serious about shifting in your life, getting honest about where you are, what is in your way and are
committed to accelerate your life to new levels, then Michael and iLiveAccountable trainings are the perfect fit for you.

</div>

<div style="clear: both;"> </div>
```

Comment: You are not using any width. Try to give width to both column and you will get in one line but better if you take both div in one div so it will look good in mobile too.

Comment: And please use css instead of adding styles into html tags.

Comment: @Frutis did you means external css file, right?

Comment: The markup on your site is different to that which you have supplied in the question. Please ensure that your issue can be accurately reproduced in the question itself, if/when your site gets fixed the question will lose all purpose.

Comment: @Leo Yes, I meant to use a style sheet. Styling inside html just makes a big mess and it's harder to read the code later.

Comment: @Frutis yes agree with you and m mentioning one line. Use inline style only when you want to override or its necesarry.

Comment: @Rodel, please check my answer and let me know if its working for you or not. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to your issue, let me show you code which will be helpful for you but keep in mind as it won't be responsive(not needed in question) :

```
<div style="width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <div style="margin-top: 10px; float: left;width:30%">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/tony-beatty.jpg" alt="tony-beatty" width="351" height="360" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-15670" style="margin-right: 15px; border: 1px solid #dedede; padding: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);
box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);"/>
</div>

        <div style="float: right; margin-top: 11px;width:60%;">
<h3>TONY BEATTY / CHIEF OPERATIONS OFFICER</h3>

Music Inc. Magazine calls Tony the <em>"Million Dollar Closer”</em>

After 25 years mastering the art of selling Music Inc. Magazine calls Tony the "million dollar closer.” Tony is not
only an extremely accomplished sales genius, but he considers himself a master story teller. Originally educated in
Music and Acting, Tony’s passion for story selling was express on the theatrical stage. After more than 50
productions his love of music and performance led him to small piano store in St. George Utah where he
combined story telling with enrolling people into music making.

In 2011, playing with video and Social Media, Tony was key in launching The Piano Guys YouTube Channel. To be
excellent in his new craft of video production, Tony received a B.S. Degree in Digital Film Production from Dixie
State University in 2013 which adds to his repertoire of talents. Talents he uses to enroll people into their own
story, vision, and purpose.

Because of Tony’s passion for learning the art of enrollment and personal development he has studied and trained
with some of the most well-known personal educators and facilitators from around the country, such as; Tom
Hopkins, Zig Ziglar, Brian Tracy and John Maxwell. Tony recognizes the behind every person is a story, likewise
products and services that enhance our lives are created through stories. Magic happens when stories merge and
fulfillment in life is achieved.

After training with Michael Gardner, Tony’s story telling took on a whole new meaning. “Life is a story, the human
story. Most peoples make up victim stories that get in the way who they truly are. Once we start recognizing the
truth of our story, we can then finish our story.”

Tony is energetic, enthusiastic and driven by people's success in life. He has comprehensive experience in human
relations inside and outside the retail and services arena. He is characterized as considerate, dependable,
honest, straightforward, hard-working, and personable, with strong management skills, including sales, marketing
and customer relationship management experience develop throughout the last 25 years.
Tony offers a combination of creative talents and a strong personal experience with people from all walks of life.
He devotes time to people while drawing on their energy, experiences and vision to make a positive contribution in
peoples lives.

</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">


    <div style="float: left; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid red;width:30%;">
<img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/mytestsite/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/mike-gardner.jpg" alt="mike-gardner" width="351" height="360" class="alignleft size-full wp-image-15669" style="margin-right: 15px; border: 1px solid #dedede; padding: 10px; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1); box-shadow: 3px 2px 5px 0px rgba(199,199,199,1);"/>
</div>

    <div style="float: right; margin-top: 11px; border: 1px solid red;width:60%;">
<h3>MICHAEL GARDNER / CHIEF EXECUTIVE OFFICER</h3>

<p>Michael Gardner is known as the Master Trainer.</p>

<p>Michael is able to train students at a new depth of knowledge that they have not experienced before, their lives
truly changed. They are able to create a passion for life and newfound wealth. Gifted would be an understatement
in referring to Michael Gardner.</p>

<p>Michael has spent the past 25 years challenging and inspiring over 10,000 people to discover that they are more
powerful than they believe. As a result, he is the premier trainer and coach and his field. Michael's direct
approach, results driven training and coaching has been experienced by CEOs, entrepreneurs, small business
owners, network marketing founders and distributors, athletes, entertainers, students and parents, and anyone
who has a desire to discover they are more powerful than they believe.

Michael has one purpose and one purpose only. That is to support his students to get what they want and more.
His students and clients discover that Michael is very direct, honest and focused. His passion is to change and
support them in their pursuits of self discovery.

Michael has a unique ability to point out the lies and stories people tell themselves to justify where they have fallen short. Even those who have achieved amazing levels of success in life are surprised by how much greater the
results they create are as a result of participating in Michael's training. Past students and clients share a greater sense of power in their lives, as well as becoming more effective in their careers, and a greater sense of peace and fulfillment in their lives.

The main focus of Michael's training and coaching are: accountability, commitment, current pension, honesty,
integrity and trust.

Whether you feel you are successful in your personal life or not, whether you feel you are already fulfilled and life is good, you will benefit exponentially to Michael's training and coaching.

If you are serious about shifting in your life, getting honest about where you are, what is in your way and are
committed to accelerate your life to new levels, then Michael and iLiveAccountable trainings are the perfect fit for you.</p>

</div>

<div style="clear: both;"> </div>
</div>
```

Above code is just solution for your question. But whenever you are using float or making structure, try to bind them in parent div and then work according to them.

What i did is, i bind your 2 div which are having float(left and right) and then i gave width as div is block element and it will take full width so give them fix width(in px or %) and then use float so they will be in one line. (but in above code image will override on text as i did not made them responsive). Also try to use clear both after floated element but in container or else it will create issue. Hope it will help. Let me know if you any issue :)